# Using an alternate coordinate system inside a pane or region

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to set up a pane such that objects placed within that pane use a coordinate system other than JavaFX "scene pixels". For example,
1024 units in my coordinate system might correspond to 1 "scene pixel"
(is there a better name for the units that JavaFX uses?). However: The
objects that are *inside* the objects that I add to the pane need to
work in "scene pixels" (for example; Labels seem to want to work in
pixel positions when rendering text).

The gist below shows a simple example of the setup I'm looking for, but it has problems.

I create one container group (actually a Pane) that adds a transform
such that 1 unit == 32 pixels. I add objects to this container. Each
object I add has an *external* pane with a size and position specified
in units, and an *internal* pane that solely exists to invert the scale
of the transform of the *external* pane. Inside this *internal* pane, I
can add Labels and so on and these all render correctly.

I set up bindings between the transforms so that I can effectively
scale and pan the view inside the pane by adjusting the transform on the group container. However: Something about this setup seems to be confusing
something inside JavaFX; the results I'm seeing onscreen don't seem to
match what JavaFX believes the bounds of various objects are. This
causes visual issues when I try to do things like set borders on
objects, and also seems to confuse ScenicView.

https://gist.github.com/io7m/20b071e11da2dcd96896a43fad6df644

Here's a shot with the container group selected (looks correct):

[image]

Here's a shot with the *external* pane of the bottom object selected:

[image]

Note that, although the object actually renders onscreen as the right
size (one of the pale grey boxes), ScenicView seems to believe that the
object's bounds are 1x1: They *are* 1x1, but they're 1x1 when expressed
in my custom coordinate system, not in JavaFX "scene pixels". You can just barely see this in the screenshot: There's a tiny single pixel in the top left corner of the object that ScenicView is highlighting to show what it thinks the bounds are.

Here's a shot with the *internal* pane of the bottom object selected:

[image: https://ataxia.io7m.com/2019/08/10/view2.png]

This looks correct in the sense that the bounds encompass the label and
nothing else.

Am I doing something wrong here? I can't tell if I'm basically abusing
transforms or not.

Comment: Iv'e seen your discussion on the JavaFX development list. The close reason is clearly stated - you're asking "what's wrong?" without providing a [mcve] that would allow to answer that. If the external gist is an MCVE, then inline it in your question.

Comment: The concept of a MCVE is not a "magic hammer" and everything is a nail!  Sometimes, there's too much complexity involved to be able to create a MCVE.  This was a well written and documented question/subject, and IMHO should not be marked as off topic.

Comment: @AdrianRomanelli You can ask a question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com as to why the question was closed. There are rules on this site that say what is a good question for this site and what isn't. One of the rules is that these type of question must have an MCVE. If you can't show one, then this site is not the place for the question, regardless of how well it was written. It is not a matter of your opinion, it's the rules. There are other software-related site on StackExchange like CodeReview and SoftwareEngineering that might be a better match for off-topic SO questions.

Comment: I understand rules and this post is not an easy one to answer. "I set up bindings between the transforms so that I can effectively scale and pan the view inside the pane by adjusting the transform on the group container. However: Something about this setup seems to be confusing something inside JavaFX; the results I'm seeing onscreen don't seem to match what JavaFX believes the bounds of various objects are." Thats the question right there, the dev is having a problem with "bindings between the transforms", and shows how he set up the bindings to back his point. Bugs can no show via MCVE.

Comment: @AdrianRomanelli "*the dev is having a problem with "bindings between the transforms", and shows how he set up the bindings to back his point.*" But he doesn't show how, there isn't any code in the question, and that's *exactly* the close reason. If you're not dealing with concurrency or a convoluted tech stack, an MCVE is almost always possible. If the gist reproduces the issue, he can paste it in the question, as he was told to do.

Comment: We can go back and forth on this, and these in-line comments are not the place to do it, but I stand by what I've said, and I disagree with your assertion that an MCVE is easily possible for the problem he is describing. Others may have had dealt with the same problem the poster has, and just from the description given could offer a solution, but cannot, when the question is put on hold. Being too trigger-happy with requesting MCVE's and disqualifying a question for lack of one is a problem on this site, unfortunately. It shouldn't be mandatory, just preferred, to supply a MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something very similar in my projects. In contrast to your approach I am not using panes. I only use groups instead and haven't noticed any problems so far. Maybe there is just a bug in ScenicView.

I don't know whether this is relevant for you too but at least in my case I also had to apply the inverse scaling to all relevant shape attributes like, e.g., the stroke width. I only wanted to have the placement of the outer geometry to be scaled but I still wanted to specify the stroke width in pixels.

This can quite easily become very complicated to handle but technically I have not experienced any problem with this approach.